# Travel Chart for the Forgotten Realms

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms, travel

I've got a game set in the Sword Coast and Savage Frontier area of the Forgotten Realms. Is there a book or online resource that I can look at that has travel times between the various locations? For example, I have characters traveling from Waterdeep to Yartar.  I'd like to know the road distance and time from Waterdeep to Red Larch, then Red Larch to Triboar, the Triboar to Yartar.

I know that travel times depend on the mode of transportation. Something with the distances is fine. I can extrapolate time from the distance based on walking, riding, etc.

I also know that the big maps have legends that can be used to get distance information. First, I don't have those maps. I have a bunch of map images on my computer. Many of them chopped into smaller regional maps. Second, a chart of the distances is easier and faster than measuring all the time.

Comment: While I think one could make this into a stack-suitable question about "how to do these things effectively," as it is, this is no longer on-topic.

Answer (score 17):

I know it isn't the first answer you're looking for, but [this link](http://media.wizards.com/2015/images/dnd/resources/Sword-Coast-Map_HighRes.jpg) is a free huge hi-res map of the Sword Coast direct from WotC with a map scale.  It looks like it would be pretty easy to figure out the distances on that map, using that scale.  For example, I figure the journey from Waterdeep to Triboar, based on this map, is about 300 miles.

Comment: There are a multiple of those kind of maps online, but I think this answer is sufficient. Therefor I won't add more link, but know that google is your friend ;).

Comment: @Me_Maikey I've Googled this and found lots of maps. I even found a Windows program that took distance and terrain and transport type and calculated travel times. I didn't find what I was looking for.  It might not exist but I figured I'd ask. I might have to make what I'm looking for.

Comment: @AndrewCooper I have browsed the web some more and I pretty much found 2 things. 1: [Another map](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/File:Map_-_Faerun_-_3E.jpg). 2: Mentions of this table not existing.

Comment: @Me_Maikey I don't think that map is canonical at this point -- it's a map from 3e and the distances based on the map scale for locations on the Sword Coast do not match up to the current canonical map (the link I posted) of the Sword Coast.

Answer (score 5):

[This site](https://www.aidedd.org/atlas/index.php?map=R&l=1) has a Forgotten Realms map that allows you to calculate distances between two points as the crow flies, or along a specific travel route (road or river) by using waypoints. I compared it to maps in WOTC 5e adventures and it seems to be accurate. It's not quite as handy as a chart listing all the cities and towns, but still handy and a lot easier than trying to measure a scale along a map route.