# Calculating distance on a map

Tags: travel, maps, map-making

I'm running a campaign in the Sword Coast, and like to provide consistent travel distance and time to my players. As far as I could find, there are no distance charts. And even if there were, they are unlikely to provide all locations (but I might stand corrected!).

A solution could be a piece of software which can open the high resolution Sword Coast map, in which I can draw lines, and which then tells me the length in pixels of the lines, so I could covert that back into miles, and ultimately derive a travel time.

Does anyone know of something to do this in?

Related:

- [Travel Chart for the Forgotten Realms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74112/travel-chart-for-the-forgotten-realms)

Comment: As written, this is a tool recommendation question, [which is off topic for the stack](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5883/62294). If there is a particular map resource you are using from officially published material, you could rephrase the question to ask about that specific one and we may be able to help you decipher distances from there.